# finding specific immediate children of an element using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, traversal

Following DOM structure:

```
<ul>
  <li class="item">yes</li>
  <li>no</li>
  <li class="item">yes</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="item">no</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Assuming I have the outer `<ul>` in `$ul`. How do I get the **two immediate children** which have the `item`-class?

In **jQuery** I would write something like this:

```
$ul.children().filter(".item")
$ul.children(".item")
$ul.find("> .item")
```

How do I to this with **Prototype**?

I tried the following ...

```
$ul.select("> .item") //WRONG
```

... but it does does exactly the opposite and returns the **one inner** `<li>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would do something very similar, functionally, to jQuery (1st example), although Prototype doesn't have a `filter` method, it has two more generic methods: `findAll` and `grep`. Here, you can use both. grep as explained [here](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/grep):

```
var items = ul.childElements().grep(new Selector('li.item'));
```

or findAll:

```
var items = ul.childElements().findAll(function (elt) {
  return elt.match('li.item');
});
```

And here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RuBzq/.

What you tried (`ul.select("> .item")`) doesn't work because the selector only tests descendants of `ul`. Since `ul` is unknown to the selector, `>` doesn't start from `ul` but from elements under it. So everything that is *not* an immediate descendant of `ul` will match `ul.select('> *')` for example. And that's why `ul.select('> .item')` only matches `.items` that are descendants of something *inside the set*. If jQuery works differently, that's a bummer.

Comment: thanks so much @Alsciende, your hint with grep() saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

if your ul has an id of Foo you could do this:

```
var els = $$('#foo>.item').each(function(s,i) { alert(s.innerText); });
```

Oddly enough, none of these work..

```
$('foo').getElementsBySelector('>.item').each(function(s,i) { alert(s.innerText); });
// As you say it returns the 'no' list item. Taking off the '>' doesn't work either.

$('foo').getElementsBySelector('.item').each(function(s,i) { alert(s.innerText); });
// returns all three

$('foo').up().getElementsBySelector('>.item').each(function(s,i) { alert(s.innerText); });
// returns all three
```

`getElementsBySelector` is supposed to be the equivalent of `$$()`, but clearly it's not.  Seems like a bug in Prototype to me...

This works, but seems of little value...

```
$('foo').up().getElementsBySelector('#foo>.item').each(function(s,i) { alert(s.innerText); });
```

Comment: It's not a bug. You can't use `>` this way in Prototype, see my answer. And getElementsBySelector is deprecated in favor of Element#select.